# How can you log from a Neo4j Server Plugin?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I'm trying to debug a problem in the Neo4J Server plugin I'm writing.  Is there a log I can output to?  It's not obvious where or how to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question. I think you could use Java Logging? That should be routed into the normal logging system.

Comment: Yup, this worked fine.  This is what I did:
`import java.util.logging.*;

private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("org.neo4j.examples.server.plugins");

logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
// Log a simple INFO message.
logger.info("Logger initted");`

Comment: Hummm didn't work for me but I am using the 3RC. Which log file does this end up in? ./data/log/console.log?

Answer (score 2):

Just inject `org.neo4j.logging.Log` in your class containing implementation of your Neo4j stored procedure.

```java
public class YourProcedures {

    @Context
    public Transaction tx;

    @Context
    public Log log;

    @Procedure(value = "yourProcedure", mode = Mode.READ)
    public Stream<YourResult> yourProcedure(@Name("input") String input) {
       log.debug("something");
    }
}
```

Logs are then dumped into standard Neo4j log file.
The level is controlled by `GraphDatabaseSettings.store_internal_log_level` configuration.
The level can be also changed in runtime. Just inject `DependencyResolver` bean and define this admin procedure. (The framework has listener hooked to config change which reconfigures the internal logging framework. This is the simplest solution I could find.)

```java
@Context
public DependencyResolver dependencyResolver;

@Procedure(value = "setLogLevel", mode = Mode.DBMS)
@Description("Runtime change of logging level")
public void setLogLevel(@Name("level") String level) {
    Config config = dependencyResolver.resolveDependency(Config.class);
    config.set(GraphDatabaseSettings.store_internal_log_level, Level.valueOf(level));
}
```

---

### UPDATE:

This ^ solution works, however it is insufficient when one wants to use logging the way usual in Log4j - different loggers organized in hierarchy, each logger at its own level. The `org.neo4j.logging.Log` component is just a wrapper of Log4j logger for the `GlobalProcedures` class. This logger is only one of many loggers in hierarchy. In fact, the wrapper blocks access to richer features of underlying framework. (Unfortunately, to define multiple `@Context Log` fields in `YourProcedures` class distinguished by some annotation qualifying logger is also impossible because field injection is driven by `Map<Class,instance>` so there is only one possible instance to inject for any `@Context-`annotated field according to field type.)

**Solution 1:**
Use JUL as in accepted answer. The disadvantage is, JUL redirects log event to underlying Log4j anyway so if logger hierarchy is defined in JUL, Log4j must be set to lowest possible level in order to make JUL levels sensitive.

**Solution 2:**
Use Log4j directly (i.e. `public static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("some.identifier.in.hierarchy")` in `YourProcedures`). There are some issues with redefining configuration programmatically though it is possible, I dropped this solution only because I had some trouble deploying this solution in non-docker environment.

**Solution 3:** (finally chosen)
I defined custom component `LogWithHierarchy` (it can be built from own `ExtensionFactory` loaded using `ServiceLoader`s - I was inspired in [APOC config implementation](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/4.2/core/src/main/java/apoc/ApocConfigExtensionFactory.java)). This component provides API of the form `debug(loggerName, message)`, `info(loggerName, message)` etc. The component knows original `Log`, drills down into its log4j `LoggerContext` and redirects all logging requests to particular logger in this `LoggerContext`. Log messages finally end in `debug.log`. With this solution the original log4j logger hierarchy is fully utilized, levels can be changed dynamically in runtime (`setLogLevel` must be changed to operate on aforementioned `LoggerContext`) and still everything is implemented using standard Neo4j plugin support.