# Neo4j server won't create data/log dir and files

Tags: plugins, service, neo4j, tags, directory

Working with Neo4j server as a WIN service with a plugin extension.
The server is not creating the log files (which should be found under data\log)
and I can't see why.
I went through all conf files and they look perfectly fine.
In my app I'm writing the logs via java.util.logging.logger as 
instructed in the documentation and suggested here:
[How can you log from a Neo4j Server Plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704687/how-can-you-log-from-a-neo4j-server-plugin)

Did anyone had similar experience or can direct me to the solution?

P.S
The plugin extension works fine.

Thank you.

Comment: On windows they might be somewhere under Application Support? Perhpas this helps: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/4142 Also which Neo4j version are you using?

Comment: Super! This is the solution. Thank you my friend! You should post an answer so i can vote it as the correct one.

Comment: Where did you actually find the log files? Perhaps you could write it  up as a quick blog post that we could link to?